# Evaluating a summation

Tags: summation, perturbation-theory

I am trying to solve a homework question in which a part involves the evaluation of a summation.

The summation is:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i+1}
$$

and this is my attempt which i am stuck at. Any lead into this would be help full.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n (2^{2i})(2) = 2\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i}
$$

when i expand this out like so
$$
2\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i} = (2)(1+2^2+2^4+2^6 + ... + 2^{2n})
$$

I don't see or know any existing summation that can help me solve this or any way to use pertubation to solve this. Again any lead into helping me out will go a long way

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1: $2^{2i} = 4^i$

Hint 2: $(1+x+x^2+...+x^n)(1-x) = 1-x+x-x^2+x^2-x^3+...+x^n-x^{n+1}$

Comment: ...how stupid of me. such an insult to my intelligence. Oh well thanks a lot anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the steps you have and the identity $$(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)=1-x^{n-1}\Longrightarrow \sum_{i=0}^n x^i=\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric series of the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^n r^n = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$

In your case, $r=2^2=4$.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a direct calculation by using the index of the summation. Let 
$$
S=\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i+1}=2\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i}.
$$
We have
$$
2S=2\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i+2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}2^{2i}=\sum_{i=0}^n2^{2i}-1+{2}^{2n+2}=\frac{S}{2}-1+2^{2n+2}.
$$
Solve the equation with variable $S$ we obtain
$$
S=\frac{2}{3}(2^{2n+2}-1).
$$